# Is there a transaction book in which to look for the mined bitcoins?

Tags: wallet

In March 2008, I joined a bitcoin mining program for a day I remember that they were not confirmed, then the inclusion in mining was authorized with enamel (not the one I'm writing from at the moment) Can I from somewhere, is there a transaction book in which to look for the mined bitcoins?

Comment: That is very implausible, given that Bitcoin didn't exist until January 2009, and the first mining pools only appeared at the end of 2010.

Answer (score 1):

> **Is there a transaction book in which to look for the mined bitcoins?**

No.

The Bitcoin blockchain is a transaction journal, but it does not link mining rewards to people's names.

---

> **In March 2008, I joined a bitcoin mining program**

I recall the Bitcoin "whitepaper" was written only in late 2008 and published early 2009. So it was impossible to mine Bitcoin in March 2008 - Bitcoin didn't exist. The first block mined, the so-called Genesis block, was mined on Jan. 3, 2009.